# Who killed the husband?

Tags: logical-deduction, mystery

> There is a round house with only one room. There is a maid who does
>   everything, a butler who usually gets the mail, an annoying husband,
>   and a lazy wife in the house.
>
> The husband is murdered on a Sunday and on that same Sunday the
>   detective comes. It has to be someone in the house because all the prints on
>   the door are just of the members of the household. He asks each of them what
>   they were doing.
>
> The **maid** says "**I was sweeping a corner.**"
>
> The **wife** says "**I was doing the dishes.**" and
>
> the **Butler** says "**I was getting the mail.**".

**Who killed him?**

Comment: Every answer is relying that there is no mail on sunday, is this assumption correct ? Here at my place sunday is pretty much day for mails :D

Comment: @Sikorski Yes, there is no mail on sunday.

Comment: @RSP is the killer.  No one who lives in a one room house has both a maid and a butler.  Therefor, OP is lying and he did it.

Comment: In my area, there is no USPS on Sunday, but the postal service is out delivering Amazon packages. So it could depend on your definition of "mail".

Comment: Perhaps, the butler usually gets the mail, except when he chooses not to, or he forgets. That might explain how he can be getting the mail on Sunday. I often do the same thing.

Comment: @ChrisCudmore I was wondering just what the heck the diameter of that "one round room" was supposed to be, and how many beds were in it. Suppose it's about the size of a sports stadium, for instance? Maybe the husband was an eccentric billionaire who just didn't like interior walls cluttering things up?

Comment: **Theory:** The detective murdered the husband and forced the others to lie, such that it is provable they all lied pursuant to @Sikorski 's answer. **Explanation:** Nobody called the detective, so how did he know which house to go to? All the prints on the door are the members of the household, so how did the detective come inside? It has to be someone in the house, and by then, the detective had already arrived! Therefore, it is the detective all along!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> Murder on the Orient Express ?
>  Everyone is lying, there are no corners in round house, lazy wife won't do dishes when maid is there and butler can't get mail on sunday.
>  So everyone murdered collectively and are now covering for each other.

Comment: Best answer right here. All other answers, including the correct one and mine, do not make sense to me, this one does.

Comment: The spoiler is indeed a spoiler (of movie) :(

Answer (score 20):

I agree with the previous answers that:

> Everybody was lying to the detective

But the killer must be:

> The maid

because

> Quote:  "There was a maid that does everything"

Comment: so other two were just watching while maid murdered the husband ?

Comment: @Sikorski What do you expect me to say?

Comment: wait for OP perhaps :)

Comment: if it is so, shouldn't the murdered do the "dying" too, triggering a paradox?

Comment: @Sikorski (rot13)ab pyrneyl gur znvq qvq gur jngpuvat gbb. Nsgre nyy, fur *qbrf rirelguvat*, qbrfa'g fur?

Comment: I think you are taking a simple puzzle too far.

Comment: I was thinking that "the maid does everything" may only apply to tasks *inside* the house, and thus the butler could truthfully say that he fetches the mail, since that involves walking *out* of the house, which takes him beyond the maid's jurisdiction. I don't think "does everything" was meant to apply to every task that needs doing in the entire outside world. On a similar note, if there's lots of furniture and plumbing fixtures and things cluttering up that round room, there could be all sorts of "corners" on the floor that need to be swept from time to time, as the maid said.

Answer (score 13):

While another answer has been accepted, I think a more reasonable answer is:

> The detective did it.

**Explanation:**

First, note that

> the text says that the detective comes the same Sunday that the husband is murdered. It does *not* say that the detective comes *after* the husband was murdered. Also note that the detective has no alibi.

Second,

> when looking closer, there's no reason to assume that anyone was lying.

In particular,

- > The cupboard was quite dirty, especially in the corners. That's why the maid was wiping them.
- > The wife was lazy, but the husband was annoying. And he had annoyed her so much about the dishes that she did them anyway.
- > The butler had his free day on Saturday, therefore the Saturday mail wasn't yet fetched when he returned on Sunday. Therefore he fetched it at that day.

> Since all of them had an alibi, they did not do it. Thus only two options remain: Suicide, or the detective killing the husband.
>
>  But suicide is excluded because the text explicitly states that the husband was murdered.
>
>  So there's only one possibility remaining, which therefore has to be the correct one: The detective did it.

Comment: celtschk has been watching a lot of Sherlock lately.

Comment: @7_R3X hahah :P

Answer (score 5):

I actually think the killer isn't lying at all:

> the Butler says "I was *getting* the **male**.".

Comment: This was really nice! $(+1)$

Answer (score 3):

Was it

> The wife?

My reasoning for that is

> The butler AND the maid were lying (maid: there are no corners, butler: there is no mail on sundays)
>  Therefore I assume that **everybody** is lying --> And since the wife is the only person with a believable alibi (I know the wife is *lazy* but it's still possible, in contrast to the others) she is therefore the most suspicious to me

Comment: It also seems possible that the butler doesn't get the mail on Saturday, making it possible for him to "get the mail" on Sunday.

Comment: @DavidStarkey it also is possible that there was furniture in the room, creating corners for the maid to sweep. You could even argue that suicide is an option. These kind of riddles tend to have many possible solutions and you just have to guess until you stumble upon the solution that OP intended. This is not meant to be a rant - I actually enjoyed this puzzle very much.

Answer (score 2):

i think-

> The  maid did it, clearly she is lying about sweeping the corner as it is a round house.So i guess she is the killer.

Comment: Or, perhaps it could have gone like this: $\ast$ (ROT13) Fhccbfr gur znvq qvq abg qb vg. Gura gur jvsr jbhyq or ylvat orpnhfr gur znvq pbhyq or jnfuvat gur qvfurf vafgrnq... ohg jr xabj gung guvf zrnaf gur znvq vf ylvat. Gurersber gur znvq naq gur jvsr ner ylvat, gurersber gurl obgu xvyyrq gur uhfonaq! $\ast$ That's how I thought of it. $(+1)$ either way :D

Answer (score 2):

Seeing as

> The maid is the wrong choice.

The answer should be

> The butler because you do not get mail on a Sunday.

Comment: Oh, i don't know how to hide the text. My bad.

Comment: Hide using the `>!` markup.

Comment: use `>!` instead of `>`

Comment: Thank you all :)
Am I right though? Because in my country you do not usually get mail on a sunday. Not sure about others

Comment: In my country, (ROT13) ebhaq ubhfrf qba'g unir pbearef... :D $\;\;\,$ **(Copy-and-paste the illegible/unreadable message into [Rot13](https://www.rot13.com/) to reveal a secret message...)** $\;\;$ $(+1)$ by the way :P

Answer (score 1):

Let me go on the record as saying:

> it was self-murder: suicide!

I know this because

> The other three are lying in very obvious ways. Clearly, someone who was actually guilty would have prepared a more convincing alibi.

Moreover, it fits because

> this situation is super annoying for everyone involved (including the detective) and we are told that annoying stuff is the husband's domain.

QED

Comment: but then why would others lie ?

Comment: @Sikorski Maybe it happened on opposite day?

Comment: @DavidStarkey detective arrived on the same day of murder, what do you mean by opposite day ?

Comment: @Sikorski [Opposite Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opposite_Day) is a day that everything is supposed to be the opposite of reality.  So "getting the mail" would mean "not getting the mail", "sweeping a corner" would be sweeping anything but a corner, etc.

Comment: @DavidStarkey didn't know that was a thing, but I am certain it is not applicable here.

Comment: @Sikorski perhaps all the others lied out of force — I mean, who called the detective? Theory: (ROT13) Gur qrgrpgvir zheqrerq gur uhfonaq naq sbeprq gur bguref gb yvr. Nyy gur cevagf ba gur qbbe ner gur zrzoref bs gur ubhfrubyq, fb ubj qvq gur qrgrpgvir pbzr vafvqr?

Comment: @DavidStarkey if it was opposite day, why would the detective come by? Good ol' [opposite day](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/60110/its-opposite-day), heheh :P

Answer (score 0):

> The Maid... no sweeping corners in a round house.

This was probably too easy for this platform :(

Comment: Or is there maybe more to it? A lazy wife doing the dishes, a butler that got the mail but did not leave prints on the door (whats a "family-member" in that regard?). Could have been a collective job of wife and maid. both are lying and should have noticed the other one killing the husband, when they are indoors, while the butler gets the mail.

Comment: No, it's not easy. just read and think again.

Answer (score 0):

The one who

> lied

And the only one who certainly

> lied

is

> the maid: she could not sweep in the **corner** witihn a **round** room.

Comment: All 3 lied :) No mail on Sunday. And who does her own dishes when you have a maid.

Answer (score 0):

> Not enough clues. The maid is lying, there are no corners. But that doesn't make her guilty of murder. This will be unsolved without more evidence.